# libvirtd - Getting vps to use existing bridge

Tags: linux, centos, kvm-virtualization, bridge

I've been working on getting KVM running on CentOS 6.4 and ran into a snag. After pouring through several online docs about setting up a bridge for the vps to connect to, and manually attempting to make the necessary changes, I finally came across [this article](http://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Unable_to_add_bridge_br0_port_vnet0:_No_such_device) which demonstrates a automagical way to do it:

```
virsh iface-bridge eth1 br0
```

Now when I do `brctl show` I get the following:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.001b78bb915a       yes             eth1
```

Everything looking good so far. In my domain config I have the following network construct:

```
<interface type='network'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:a3:dd:2c'/>
  <source network='br0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

Yet, when I try to start the domain I keep getting the following error:

```
error: Failed to start domain service-a-2
error: Network not found: no network with matching name 'br0'
```

After some more searching around, I found that I can list out the networks available to hypervisor by issuing the following:

```
$ ->  virsh net-list --all
```

But in my case, it's empty. So I found [this article](http://libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html) which demonstrates how to setup to use an existing bridge, so my config looks like:

```
<network>
  <name>br0</name>
  <forward mode="bridge"/>
  <bridge name="br0" />
</network>
```

I added it to hypervisor by way of `virsh net-define /tmp/br0.xml`. Then I started the network and my domain, but now when I issue `ifconfig` command I am a seeing vnet0 entry:

```
vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:A3:DD:2C
inet6 addr: fe80::fc54:ff:fea3:dd2c/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Which doesn't make sense, shouldn't the domain use the existing br0 bridge? Does a new vnetX tunnel(?) get created for every vps started by hypervisor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is making absolute sense. What happens when you set up a bridge, is a dummy bridge device with nothing plugged into it (`brctl show` will list no NICs under it).

When you attach the bridge to a physical interface, it will appear as one of the interfaces plugged into the bridge, and through which in fact real traffic will go, but that is only one interface of the bridge. When you start a VM it comes up with a tap device, which should also be plugged into the switch, so the switch can have two interfaces and move traffic between the two. Just think of the bridge as a network switch, where the VM is plugged (the tap is that vnet0 device) and the real NIC is plugged too. More VMs can be plugged into this bridge, all their traffic will go to the network through the physical NIC you have attached to the bridge.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. When I first setup the vps I didn't notice the new interfaces, so when I started noticing them after a recent rebuild, I thought I did something wrong.